# MySQL Error Code 1054......Newbie in need of assistance

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I am a new website developer and I have recently picked up a "PHP and MySQL In Easy Steps" book to assist me in learning the languages.

Everything worked fine and seemed pretty straight forward, but for some reason my last three excercises I have gotten error messages. And i looked at the example\finished files that go with the book and they are identical.
Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code here. I get a `1054 error message`:

```
(42S22) : Unknown column 'make' in field list.
```

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS phones
(
  id    INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  make      CHAR(16) ,
  model     CHAR(16) ,
  platform  CHAR(16) 
) ;

INSERT INTO phones ( make , model , platform   )
VALUES  
( "Apple" , "iPhone" , "iOS" ) , 
( "RIM" , "Curve" , "BlackBerry" ) ,
( "HTC" , "Desire" , "Android" ) ,
( "Nokia" , "Lumia" , "Windows" ) ;

SELECT * FROM phones ;

SELECT id , make FROM phones ;
SELECT make , model FROM phones ;
SELECT id , platform FROM phones ;
```

Comment: If your book makes mention of the MySQL extension (PHP functions start with `mysql_`), send it back. The MySQL extension has been deprecated. You should use PDO or MySQLi instead

Answer (score 5):

Do you have an already-existing phones table lying around without that column? If so, then the IF NOT EXISTS part of CREATE TABLE will have that statement ignored.